# Acesso à biblioteca DLL feita em Delphi a partir do Java

Tags: java, delphi, struct, dll

Estou desenvolvendo uma ferramenta para reconhecimento biométrico usando o SDK fornecido em formato DLL, desenvolvido em Delphi. Para o acesso à DLL a partir do Java, estou usando JNA.

O template da digital (a parte mais importante) é um objeto que se refere a este trecho (em Delphi):

```pascal
type
  CIS_Digital = packed record
    intSize: integer;
    pDigital: Pointer
  end;

pCIS_Digital = ^CIS_Digital;
```

**Como desenvolver algo equivalente em Java?**

---

Basicamente, preciso chamar as seguintes funções da DLL:

```
SDK_CIS_Iniciar(int cnpj, int detectaFake);
SDK_CIS_LerDigital(pCIS_Digital digital);
SDK_CIS_CompararDigital(pCIS_Digital amostra1, pCIS_Digital amostra2);
SDK_CIS_Finalizar();
```

Olhando o **exemplo fornecido, desenvolvido em Delphi**, vi que o objeto `pCIS_Digital`, que é passado nas funções `SDK_CIS_LerDigital()` e `SDK_CIS_CompararDigital()`, é do tipo (`type`) declarado no trecho de código mais acima.

No mesmo exemplo, antes de chamar o método `SDK_CIS_LerDigital()`, o objeto `pCIS_Digital` é instanciado e vai vazio onde então é "preenchido" através da função.

O leitor é o [Techmag BioFlex](http://www.techmag.com.br/bioflex/), que é baseado nos leitores Futronic (FS-80).

Pesquisando, vi que o objeto `pCIS_Digital` (do trecho de código), faz acesso à memória para ler as informações que o leitor grava nela escreve.

Depois de muitas pesquisa, **acho** que devo desenvolver algum objeto equivalente em Java, estendendo das classes `Structure` ou `Memory`, do JNA.

[image: Lista de funções do SDK fornecido]

---

## Atualização: Informações sobre meu código

Leio e armazeno duas vezes a minha digital utilizando o método `SDK_CIS_LerDigital`, depois comparo as duas utilizando o método `SDK_CIS_CompararDigital`, que sempre retorna `0` (comando não executado).

"Printei" os objetos `intSize` e `pDigital` após ler a digital, `intSize` retorna `0` e `pDigital` retorna `null`.

Interface com os métodos da DLL:

```
public interface SDK_CIS extends StdCallLibrary {

static SDK_CIS INSTANCE = (SDK_CIS) Native.loadLibrary("SDK_CIS", SDK_CIS.class);

    public String SDK_CIS_Versao();

    public String SDK_CIS_Retorno(int resposta);

    public int SDK_CIS_Iniciar(long cnpj, int fake);

    public int SDK_CIS_Finalizar();

    public int SDK_CIS_LerDigital(CIS_Digital.ByReference digital);

    public int SDK_CIS_CancelarLeitura();

    public int SDK_CIS_CompararDigital(CIS_Digital.ByReference pAmostra1, CIS_Digital.ByReference pAmostra2);
}
```

Classe que estende Structure, referente ao objeto CIS_Digital:

```
public class CIS_Digital extends Structure {

    public static class ByReference extends CIS_Digital implements Structure.ByReference {}

    public int intSize;
    public Pointer pDigital;

    @Override
    protected List<String> getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("intSize", "pDigital");
    }
}
```

Método responsável por ler duas vezes qualquer digital e compará-las:

```
public void leEcomparaDigitais() {

        SDK_CIS leitor = SDK_CIS.INSTANCE;

        try {
            // TROQUEI MEU CNPJ POR ZEROS, PARA NÃO EXPOR MINHA LICENÇA    
            leitor.SDK_CIS_Iniciar(Long.parseLong("00000000000000"), 0);

            CIS_Digital.ByReference amostra1 = new CIS_Digital.ByReference();

            leitor.SDK_CIS_LerDigital(amostra1);

            try {
                // AGUARDA 1 SEGUNDO PARA LER PELA SEGUNDA VEZ
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            CIS_Digital.ByReference amostra2 = new CIS_Digital.ByReference();

            leitor.SDK_CIS_LerDigital(amostra2);

            int resp = leitor.SDK_CIS_CompararDigital(amostra1, amostra2);

            // EXIBE RESPOSTA
            // 0 -> COMANDO NAO EXECUTADO
            // 1 -> COMANDO EXECUTADO COM SUCESSO
            System.out.println(resp);

        } finally {
            leitor.SDK_CIS_Finalizar();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Favor, verifique o resultado da função `leitor.SDK_CIS_LerDigital(amostra1);`. O problema pode estar na leitura e você não está verificando o retorno

Comment: Olá! Chamei o método SDK_CIS_Versao e o mesmo imprime a versão do SDK (2014.001.02.1404).

Comment: Esta é a primeira vez que trabalho com acesso à DLLs. Não faço ideia sobre qual é a calling convention da dll SDK_CIS. Irei pesquisar a respeito. Obrigado mais uma vez.

Comment: Numa rápida pesquisa, localizei a seguinte informação:

Based on the Pascal programming language's calling convention, the parameters are pushed on the stack in left-to-right order (opposite of cdecl), and the callee is responsible for balancing the stack before return.

This calling convention was common in the following 16-bit APIs: OS/2 1.x, Microsoft Windows 3.x, and Borland Delphi version 1.x. Modern versions of the Windows API use stdcall, which still has the callee restoring the stack as in the Pascal convention, but the parameters are now pushed right to left.

Comment: LerDigital retona 1. (1 = comando executado com sucesso).

Comment: `amostra1.intSize` retorna sempre 0?

Comment: Sim, @EProgrammerNotFound. intSize sempre 0 e pDigital sempre null. =(

Comment: Você possui uma versão em Delphi desse sistema que está funcionando?

Comment: Possuo sim, @EProgrammerNotFound. Com o fonte e tudo mais.

Comment: tenta correr isso em jar no delphi( programas o pretendido em java e no delphi chamas um jar.

Comment: Eu vi esse post aqui no SOF em inglês, mas o código da resposta tá em português. Talvez você possa chegar à pessoa que respondeu por meio do chat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30945826/function-mapping-delphi-dll-with-java-jna

Comment: A DLL é 32 ou 64 bits? Qual a versão do java que você pretende utilizar (exemplo: 1.7 32bits, 1.8 64bits) ? Se precisar recompilar a DLL (em Delphi), você pode alterar o código-fonte dela?

Comment: Uma sugestão um pouco diferente, você poderia fazer uma interface c/c++ com a dll e implementar os métodos em Java usando JNI. Java+Delphi usando JNI: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/747/jni-interacao-java-e-outras-linguagens.aspx; Delphi DLL e c++: https://sergworks.wordpress.com/2013/12/13/consuming-delphi-interfaces-in-dephi-and-c/; JNI: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaNativeInterface.html.

Comment: pelo que sei deves chamar o jar no delphi, esse jar deve gerar-te um output depois é so partir a string

Answer (score 1):

Isso pode se tratar de um erro devido a `calling convention` das funções na DLL.

Assumindo que você tenha o código fonte original da DLL em Delphi, você pode alterar a `calling convention` das funções incluindo a cláusula `stdcall` no final da definição, por exemplo:

```
function foobar( x: Integer ): Integer; stdcall;
```

Espero que seja útil!